# xampp server http://localhost/ redirects to http://www.localhost/ and doesn't work

Tags: drupal, localhost

I have a drupal website and have been using an `XAMPP` local server; I have several sites on the server and this morning they all worked fine.

On my main site `Site 1`, I was getting duplicate sites, google was finding http://www.site1.com and http://site1.com, so I edited the `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I removed the # from the last 2 lines and uploaded my site.

Hey presto, no more duplicate site on google, however now when I try and log in to my local server instead of it going to http://localhost/site1 it tries to link to http://www.localhost/site1 instead and I get an error saying

```
Oops! Internet Explorer could not find www.localhost.
```

My other sites still work fine which suggests it was something to do with the redirect. I have changed the .htaccess file back but it makes no difference.

I have scoured the web with little luck. I have tried changing local host for 127.0.0.1, but I still get the same message.

I'm a newbie and have been tearing my hair out for days now, to no avail. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Rules related to rewriting of non www to www urls have been turned on .
Commenting those lines should do the trick. Try clearing your browser cache or try from new browser.